# How to efficiently develop client-side code for a web app without installing a local backend?

Tags: javascript, configuration

One of my team members is working only on client-side (Javascript) development for a web app with a large and complex backend.

I would like to avoid the need for him install and configure a local copy of the backend.
However, I wouldn't want him to need to push every small change to the dev server just so that he can test it.

We thought about getting the client to make the requests directly to the dev server, instead of to the same domain (the localhost) but this doesn't seem practical due to cross-domain request policies and authentication problems (cookies aren't getting sent).

What are some elegant solutions for developing clients without having a local backend?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complicated your backend is, you might be able to create a mock backend using a lightweight web framework like Sinatra.  I've had some success with this technique, but the services I've been mocking have been fairly simple.  In some cases the mock backend mostly serves static JSON files.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to [map the URIs](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-remote/) of the dev server's web services to localhost (where I run a light weight web server that serves up my static development code).